# $V=\left \{ x\in P | x(0)-x(i)=0)\right \}$ is a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, complex-numbers

Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$. Consider
$$S=\left \{ p\in V | p(0)-p(i)=0)\right \}$$
where $i^2=-1$. Is $S$ a vector space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$S$ is a subset of $V$, so we check if addition and scalar multiplication are closed in $S$.

Let $p,q\in S$ and $z\in \Bbb C$. $(p+q)(x):=p(x)+q(x)$  Then
$$(p+q)(0)-(p+q)(i)=p(0)+q(0)-p(i)-q(i)=p(0)-p(i)+q(0)-q(i)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow (p+q)(x) \in  S$$

$$\text{Also, }z*(p(0)-p(i))=z(0)=0 \Rightarrow z*p(x) \in S$$
So $S$ is a subspace of $V$, and hence a vector space.